# can we build custom ROM for touch table(27" inch monitor) having Android os?

Tags: android, android-tv, custom-rom

I want to build custom rom for android os (touch table),for customizing  launcher and specific apps only available in that.

like this table :https://popshap.com/27-inch-touch-table

Comment: Far too broad a question.  Limit it to how to do one specific thing and it might be on topic.

Comment: ok, can we build custom rom for android touch table ?